# LWJGL - Interleaved VAO/VBO not texturing

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

I have been attempting to transition my game's prototype renderer from it's immediate mode testing implementation to an actual VAO/VBO implementation. The VBO is rendering on screen, but is refusing to texture. Below is the simplest test class that shows the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //                          VertX,VertY         TexX,  TexY
    float[] data = new float[] {0.0f, 0.0f,     0.25f, 0.75f,
                                0.0f, 64.0f,    0.25f, 1.0f,
                                64.0f, 64.0f,   0.5f, 1.0f,

                                0.0f, 0.0f,     0.25f, 0.75f,
                                64.0f, 64.0f,   0.5f, 1.0f,
                                64.0f, 0.0f,    0.5f, 0.75f};

    glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));
    if (!glfwInit())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

    long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1600, 900, "TEST", 0, 0);
    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GL.createCapabilities();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1600, 900, 0, 0.000001, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    int vboId = glGenBuffers();
    int vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();

    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 4*Float.BYTES, 0);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*Float.BYTES, 4*Float.BYTES);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);   
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glTranslatef(50, 50, 0);

    Texture t = new Texture(TEST.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test/WallFloor.png"));

    while (!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
        GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


            glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);



            glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            t.bind();

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);


            glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);

            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);   
            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            /* Equivelent immediate mode code - that works
            t.bind();

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 0.75f);
            glVertex2f(0, 0);
            glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 1f);
            glVertex2f(0, 64);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.75f);
            glVertex2f(64, 0);

            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1f);
            glVertex2f(64, 64);
            glTexCoord2f(0.25f, 1f);
            glVertex2f(0, 64);
            glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.75f);
            glVertex2f(64, 0);
            glEnd();
            */

    }
}
```

The texture bind call is the following (where wrap = GL_REPEAT and filter = GL_NEAREST):

```
public void bind()
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(target, id);
    glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filter);
    glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filter);
    glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrap);
    glTexParameteri(target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrap);
}
```

Having spent the weekend googling it an not finding an answer, am I doing something horribly wrong? I have also tested using immediate mode, which does still render with a texture.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, you are mixing core profile code (`glVertexAttribPointer`) with non-core profile (`glTexCoordPointer`)

But the real problem comes from the wrong stride and offset used. Stride defines how large the data of one vertex is, while the offset specifies how far from the beginning of each vertex the actual data starts. In your case, every vertex consists of 4 floats thus the stride has to be `4 * Float.BYTES`. The positions are the first two floats in each vertex (offset 0) while the texture coordinates are the 3rd and 4th floats which means `offset = 2 * Float.BYTES`. The correct code could look somehow like this (note the usage of `glVertexPointer` instead of `glVertexAttribPointer`):

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, false, 4*Float.BYTES, 0);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*Float.BYTES, 2*Float.BYTES);
```

**Edit**

The usage of your VAOs is also wrong. In the initialization you store the glVertexPointer/glTexCoordPointer to the VAO `vaoId`. But in the rendering code you bind VAO 0 instead. Most probably the attribute settings are not present when drawing. In addition, I'm not absolutely sure whether VAOs work together with fixed function calls. In this case you can remove all of the VAO calls.

Comment: The code above produces an un-textured square, or an access violation, depending on whether 'glVertexAttribPointer' or 'glVertexPointer'. Also, as a query then, what would be the core profile replacement for 'glTexCoordPointer'?

Comment: The core-profile replacement would be `glVertexAttribPointer`. Attributes are defined by the shader, so query the location of the texture coordinate attribute and use this as first parameter for `glVertexAttribPointer`.